# Деплой сайта, написанного на Java

Tags: java, tomcat, развертывание

Пытаюсь развернуть сайт, написанный на Java с использованием фреймворка Vaadin на платном хостинге. Сделал вcё согласно туториала - скопировал `.war` архив в корень проекта и его разархивировал.

При попытке предварительного просмотра сайта из cPanel, или при переходе по ссылке, предоставленой хозяином хостинга открывается окно приветсвия сервера Tomcat. Возможно есть какие-то нюансы в настройке `pom.xml`, или конкренто плагина Tomcat.

Comment: ручной деплой прост.. заходишь на томкат сайт.ру/manager, переходим в секцию WAR file to deploy, выбираем war-файл на пк и Deploy его на сервер, после деплоя в таблице Applications появляется ваше приложение, нажав на ссылку в колонке Path, откроется то, что и требовалось, вот и все

Answer (score 2):

Приветственная страница томкэта сама по себе задеплоина в рут, ваш проект сейчас есть на сервере только в контексте http://localhost:8080/app_name/ 
Для того чтобы он запустился в рут контексте есть два варианта:

1й примитивный - назвать ваш app_name.war в  ROOT.war лучше сделать через мавен, но можно и ручками. Дальше заходим на томкэт выбираем app manager, на странице видим список Applications и тот что у вас стоит в разделе Path с значением "/" вы должны убрать нажав на udeploy.
После этого в разделе "WAR file to deploy" выбираем свой ROOT.war. Теперь ваше приложение доступно в root контексте, то есть сразу после /

2й вариант через конфигурацию conf/server.xml

Сначала забрасываем свой war файл в папку webapps, потом идем в папку conf открываем server.xml и в самом конце перед  добавляем строку

```
<Context path="" docBase="app_name" debug="0" reloadable="true">
            <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

Где app_name имя вашего .war файла